# Mapbox point is not as accurate as the point in Mapbox studio dataset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, coordinate-systems, mapbox-marker

Hello

I started to work with mapbox about a month ago now but I'm stuck with some issues.
One of theses issues are related to the accuracy of the point displayed in Mapbox.
To sum up, I uploaded geojson data through mapbox studio dataset. When I look up for a particular point (to check) I see that the point is in the right place. However when I go the Mapbox Style editor and when I added the source of my previous dataset (I'm looking for the same point to check), I realized that the point is not at the right place anymore (few meters away).

Do you have any idea please ?

This the point in the dataset : 
[image]

And the following is in mapbox style studio : 
[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What are the point coordinates?? I've done that many times between both and unless you are removing decimals in the coords they are exactly the same

Comment: I checked the coordinates, they were good. But I found the issue (see my answer below for more details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
The issue came from the convertion from the dataset to the tileset...

When you upload your data through mapbox studio > dataset, to use these data you have to "transform" it into tileset (it is generated automatically to use it in mapbox studio style). So I was wondering if this transformation process removed some decimals or something. I looked to a lot of mapbox documentations page and I found [this one](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/reference/#zoom-levels). If I understood well the issue is caused by the zoom level (see the link above).

To bypass the "default" transformation from dataset to tileset, I tried to upload directly my geojson data through mapbox studio > tileset. But the issue was still present. I presume that they apply a default zoom level (Which limits accuracy) even through the mapbox studio tileset. I found a useful tool to modify the zoom level of a geojson data before uploading to mapbox studio tileset : [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe)

If I'm not wrong, according to the good options, the tool can choose the best zoom for the precisions of your coordinates. So, according to the documentation "If you aren't sure what options to use" I tried this :

```
tippecanoe -zg -o outputFile.mbtiles --drop-densest-as-needed inputData.geojson
```

Then I uploaded the outputFile into mapbox studio tileset and all the coordinates were well located !!

Comment: I think the problem you encountered is the effect caused by overzooming: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/adjust-tileset-zoom-extent